# When the name of a css class in Chrome DevTools is only an asterisk, what does the asterisk mean?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging in Chrome DevTools, I see a CSS class named with only an asterisk. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: `*` selects all elements. [It's called the universal selector.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` is a 'wildcard' meaning it matches everything.

Reference:

- [MDN Universal selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

An asterisk represents all elements. The styles applied to `*` will be applied to everything.

Here is an example. This CSS will give a red border to all elements.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```